# Coginter Clean Url

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Coginter

i want to clean url

i have url http://androidsign.com/newarticle//categories/get_categories/electronics

i want this url http://androidsign.com/newarticle/electronics

in routes file i write code

```
$route['categories/(:any)'] = "$1";
```

But this is not working

Can anybody have idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,

current : http://androidsign.com/newarticle//categories/get_categories/electronics

desired : http://androidsign.com/newarticle/electronics

then on application/config/routes.php
add this routing RULE

//if class = newarticle , method = categories , 3rd seg = get_categories ,4th (:any) wildcard
$route['newarticle/categories/get_categories/:any'] = "newarticle/electronics";

A URL containing the segments newaricle/categories/get_categories will be remapped to the class newarticle and method electronics